# Set Jira component field using groovy script

Tags: groovy, jira-rest-api, opsgenie

I am trying to create jira ticket using groovy script (on Marid server from Opsgenie.
However, I am facing issue when trying to setup component field.

```
    import com.ifountain.opsgenie.client.http.OpsGenieHttpClient
import com.ifountain.opsgenie.client.util.ClientConfiguration
import com.ifountain.opsgenie.client.util.JsonUtils
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders

LOG_PREFIX = "[${mappedAction}]:";
logger.info("${LOG_PREFIX} Will execute [${mappedAction}] for alertId ${params.alertId}");

CONF_PREFIX = "jira.";
HTTP_CLIENT = createHttpClient();
try {
    String url = params.url
    if (url == null || "".equals(url)) {
        url = _conf("url", true)
    }
    String issueKey = params.key
    String projectKey = params.projectKey
    if (projectKey == null || "".equals(projectKey)) {
        projectKey = _conf("projectKey", true)
    }
    String issueTypeName = params.issueTypeName
    if (issueTypeName == null || "".equals(issueTypeName)) {
        issueTypeName = _conf("issueType", true)
    }


    String username = params.username
    String password = params.password

    if (username == null || "".equals(username)) {
        username = _conf("username", true)
    }
    if (password == null || "".equals(password)) {
        password = _conf("password", true)
    }

    Map contentTypeHeader = [:]
    contentTypeHeader[HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE] = "application/json"
    def authString = (username + ":" + password).getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
    contentTypeHeader[HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION] = "Basic ${authString}".toString()
    contentTypeHeader[HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] = "application/json"

    def contentParams = [:]
    def fields = [:]
    def project = [:]
    def issuetype = [:]
    def transitions = [:]
    def resolution = [:]
    def customfield = [:]


    String resultUrl = url + "/rest/api/2/issue"
    if (mappedAction == "addCommentToIssue") {
        contentParams.put("body", params.body)
        resultUrl += "/" + issueKey + "/comment"
    } else if (mappedAction == "createIssue") {
        issuetype.put("name", issueTypeName)
        project.put("key", projectKey)
        fields.put("project", project)
        fields.put("issuetype", issuetype)
        fields.put("summary", params.summary)
        fields.put("description", params.description)
        String toLabel = "ogAlias:" + params.alias
        //fields.put("labels", Collections.singletonList(toLabel.replaceAll("\\s", "")))

        customfield.put("value","Test")
        fields.put("customfield_10714",customfield)


        def components = [:]
        components.put("name","Monitoring \\ Reports Async")
        logger.debug("components ${components}")
        def set = ["set":components]
        contentParams.put("components", set)





        contentParams.put("fields", fields)
```

The error I am facing is: 
ERROR: [createIssue]: Could not execute at Jira; response: 400 {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"components":"Component/s is required."}}

Would appreciate if someone can assist how to set component field on creation

Answer (score 2):

According to the JIRA's [REST API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/), you should put the components list into the fields map. Also, JIRA REST API supports only component IDs in the payload according to the doc. You should retrieve the component ID/s first, and then you can use it like this

```
def components = [
    ["id": "my_component_id_1"]
    ["id": "my_component_id_2"]
]

fields.put("components", components)
```

Please let me know if you have further questions.